# R - Plot the rolling mean of different time series in a lineplot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, zoo

I want to plot the rolling mean of data of different time series with `ggplot2`. My data have the following structure:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(episode=seq(1:1000), 
                 t_0 = runif(1000), 
                 t_1 = 1 + runif(1000), 
                 t_2 = 2 + runif(1000))
df.tidy <- gather(df, "time", "value", -episode) %>% 
  separate("time", c("t", "time"), sep = "_") %>%
  subset(select = -t)

> head(df.tidy)
#  episode time     value
#1       1    0 0.7466480
#2       2    0 0.7238865
#3       3    0 0.9024454
#4       4    0 0.7274303
#5       5    0 0.1932375
#6       6    0 0.1826925
```

Now, the code below creates a plot where the lines for time = 1 and time = 2 towards the beginning of the episodes do not represent the data because `value` is filled with NAs and the first numeric entry in `value` is for time = 0.

```
ggplot(df.tidy, aes(x = episode, y = value, col = time)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.2) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = rollmean(value, 10, align = "right", fill = NA)))
```

[image: Plot result]

How do I have to adapt my code such that the rolling-mean lines are representative of my data?

Comment: from the `rollmean` documentation: *Currently, there are methods for "zoo" and "ts" series and default methods. The default method of rollmedian is an interface to runmed. The default methods of rollmean and rollsum do not handle inputs that contain NAs. In such cases, use rollapply instead.*

Comment: You need tidyr in your example `Error in gather(df, "time", "value", -episode) : 
  could not find function "gather"`

Comment: @JackBrookes True. I forgot. I have made an edit accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is you are applying a moving average over the whole column, which makes data "leak" from one value of `time` to another.

You could `group_by` first to apply the `rollmean` to each time separately:

```
ggplot(df.tidy, aes(x = episode, y = value, col = time)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.2) + 
  geom_line(data = df.tidy %>%
              group_by(time) %>%
              mutate(value = rollmean(value, 10, align = "right", fill = NA)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for. I had the same reasoning for why I get the undesired result, but couldn't come up with a solution. Yours is great.